# Is there a command called 'screen_it' in ubuntu?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I was going through [this](http://github.com/vishvananda/novascript/blob/master/nova.sh#L153) shell script and couldn't understand the command 'screen_it' used there. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a function, defined at line 109:

```
function screen_it {
    screen -S nova -X screen -t $1
    screen -S nova -p $1 -X stuff "$2$NL"
}
```

Quoting from Screen's [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html):

```
stuff string
```

Stuff the string string in the input buffer of the current window. This is like the "paste" command but with much less overhead. You cannot paste large buffers with the "stuff" command. It is most useful for key bindings. See also "bindkey".

So, from that description, `stuff "$2$NL"` will "paste" the second argument and add a newline.

Answer (score 0):

`screen_it` is a function defined on line # 109 
https://github.com/vishvananda/novascript/blob/master/nova.sh#LID109